# Formatting Latitude and Longitude for auto-detection on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, mapping, latitude-longitude

Is there a best practice for listing Lat/Long coordinates on web sites/applications so that mobile devices will auto link to the default mapping app?

For example, if a number is listed in plain text "555-867-5309" on a web site, most mobile devices will auto link it as a phone number.

If I list the lat/long as plain text, it is not currently being detected as a mappable element.  Is there a way to write the coordinates so that the default mapping application will open them up with a single click?  I'm working with decimal based coordinates if it matters, for example:

```
22.12345,-84.123456
```

Answer (score 0):

No, afaik there is none existing.
If one exists, then the order of the coordinates would be lat,lon